# Вопрос по авторизации админа в Yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, yii2

в backend части есть контроллер, который отвечает за авторизацию

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'authorization'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['authorization'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}


public function actionAuthorization ()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    } else {
        return $this->renderPartial('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
/**
 * Logs out the current user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();
    return $this->goHome();
}
/**
 * Requests password reset.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
{
    $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        if ($model->sendEmail()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

            return $this->goHome();
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for email provided.');
        }
    }

    return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
/**
 * Resets password.
 *
 * @param string $token
 * @return mixed
 * @throws BadRequestHttpException
 */
public function actionResetPassword($token)
{
    try {
        $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
    } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
    }

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password was saved.');

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    return $this->render('resetPassword', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
}
```

И обычны контроллер

class SiteController extends Controller
   {

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        if (Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin) {
                           return $this->goHome();
                        } else {
                            Yii::$app->user->logout();
                            return $this->redirect('/authorization/');
                        }
                    }
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}

public function actionIndex()
{
     return $this->render('index');
}


}
```

Мне собственно не нравится моя идея, по авторизации админа через ACF, а именно, то, что он сначала авторизируется на сайте, а потом я его кикаю:

```
    public function behaviors()
    {
     return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        if (Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin) {
                           return $this->goHome();
                        } else {
                            Yii::$app->user->logout();
                            return $this->redirect('/authorization/');
                        }
                    }
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

По логике он вообще не должен авторизироваться если не админ.
Есть ли другие варианты?
Грубо говоря нужен rbac на две роли user и admin

Comment: Ты не внимательно посмотрел код,

Comment: а кто-нибудь понял, что хочет сделать автор вопроса? суть проблемы совершенна не раскрыта

Comment: если нужно закрыть админку от посторонних глаз и логинить только админа, то вот вам на вооружение, удобный и простой компонент: https://github.com/brussens/yii2-maintenance-mode

Comment: Я бы хотел поправить код так, что бы если user не админ,
то авторизация не проходила, простой редирект не катит, ибо тогда пользователь все равно авторизирован, поэтому я делаю Yii::$app->user->logout(); и редирект.
Я уже посоветовался нужно ставить RBAC для таких целей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ как это сделать:

1. [простой rbac](http://nix-tips.ru/yii2-prostaya-realizaciya-rbac-s-dvumya-rolyami.html)
2. [ссылка на коммит](https://github.com/gudfar/ferma/commit/8fcf9f0cc977e771f6a7614f73b59fff99bdeeb6)

Answer (score 2):

Используй RBAC - контроль доступа на оcнове ролей, больше возможностей..

Назначишь роли админов, программистов, редакторов,  пользователей и кому и куда хочешь - давай какие хочешь права....

Comment: Я знаю про RBAC,

Comment: Просто думал что есть варианты проще